# Skip blank rows when copy range to text file

Tags: excel, vba

My procedure copy *Lg1* rows form an Excel range to a text file. I want to prevent  any ***blank*** row form being copied to the text file. First cells of each row contained this formula : `=IF(L39C7=0;"";L15C20)`. As you can see, the cell is or empty ***" "***, or contains L15C20 value.

**EDIT** : here is one fulle row. All rows have same content:`[=IF(L39C7=0;"";L15C20)],[=IF(LC(-1)="";"";IF(L39C7<0;"…";"5272"))],[=IF(LC(-2)="";"";IF(L41C7<0;"…";"2302"))],[=IF(LC(-3)="";"";"salaire")],[=IF(LC(-4)="";"";"0")]`

Here is part of my code:

```
With ws
Set RngSelect = .Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstCol), Cells(31, LastCol)) 
End with
With RngSelect
For Lg1 = 1 To (LastRow - FirstRow + 1)
    If .Cells(Lg1,1).Value <> "" Then  'Here is my issue
    Txt = Txt & vbCrLf & Join$(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Rows(Lg1).Value)), vbTab)
    Next
    End If
End With
Lg2 = FreeFile()
Open FilePath For Append As #Lg2
Print #Lg2, Mid$(Txt, Len(vbCrLf) + 1)
Close Lg2
```

I have tried with no success various tests to evaluate If cell <> " " but keep having blank rows in my text file. What shall I write to solve my issue?

Thank you for help.

Comment: A minor one. Try using `Txt = Txt & (vbCrLf & Join$(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Rows(Lg1).Value)), vbTab))` to join your long string (`Txt`) once rather than twice to the other strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be better to check for blank in this way (here, for the first column within your range):

```
If Len(.Cells(Lg1, 1).Value) > 0 Then
```

Comment: I still get the blanck row. Maybe shall I add that the whole row is made of Cells which all contain the above condition cited : `=IF(L39C7=0;"";L15C20) `. I thought testing only the first cell of the row was enough, but maybe am I wrong.

Comment: you could be wrong. I can't see your data sheet. But you could try to use `CountBlank function` in such situation.

Comment: here is one fulle row. All rows have same content:`[=IF(L39C7=0;"";L15C20)],[=IF(LC(-1)="";"";IF(L39C7<0;"…";"5272"))],[=IF(LC(-2)="";"";IF(L41C7<0;"…";"2302"))],[=IF(LC(-3)="";"";"salaire")],[=IF(LC(-4)="";"";"0")]`

Comment: can't see it here... add it to your question.

Comment: the `CountBlank`function returns correctly the number of empty rows for my range, and with a condition `CountBlank <> 0`inside the `For Next`I still get the blanck rows. I suspect my issue comes from part of the code which deals with the writing to text file.

Comment: I spent the last two hours testing my code with the wrong control button : this one was NOT affected to the  procedure I was testing. Your `If`works perfectly well !!